# MYSQL Error 1452: Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1452

I'm not sure what I have done wrong with this. MySQL isn't really my thing so I thought I should ask for some help here.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "D:/Database/FMA/walkdb_dataprogProgrammeCREATE TABLE      `Programme` (
`programme_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`walk_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`programme_date` text NOT NULL,
`programme_starttime` date NOT NULL,
`programme_maxpart` int(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`programme_id`),
 KEY `walkprog_id_idx` (`walk_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `walkprog_id` FOREIGN KEY (`walk_id`) REFERENCES `Walk` (`walk_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
.csv"
INTO TABLE Programme 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Do you need any more details?

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statement should be executed elsewhere. If the table you want load your data into doesn't exist, you've got to create this table before your [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) statement.

Comment: @VMai I suggest you post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Barranka So I've done. It was too obvious for me.

Answer (score 2):

You've got mixed your `CREATE TABLE` statement into the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement. If you want to combine those two, you've got to create your table first, becauld [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) will only import into existing tables.

I assume it should be:

```
CREATE TABLE `Programme` (
    `programme_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `walk_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `programme_date` text NOT NULL,
    `programme_starttime` date NOT NULL,
    `programme_maxpart` int(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`programme_id`),
    KEY `walkprog_id_idx` (`walk_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `walkprog_id` FOREIGN KEY (`walk_id`) REFERENCES `Walk` (`walk_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

followed by

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "D:/Database/FMA/walkdb_dataprogProgramme.csv"
INTO TABLE Programme 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Maybe you would consider

> To ignore foreign key constraints during the load operation, issue a
>   SET foreign_key_checks = 0 statement before executing LOAD DATA.

for your foreign key constraint on `walk_id`.